# IE10 SVG in CSS background

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, svg

I have a problem with IE10 and SVG in CSS style. It works on chrome and firefox:

```
background-image: url(data:image/svg+xml,<svg\ version=\"1.1\"\ xmlns=\"http://www.w3.org/2000/svg\"\ width=\"32px\"\ height=\"32px\"\ viewBox=\"0\ 0\ 32\ 32\"><circle\ fill=\"red\"\ cx=\"16\"\ cy=\"16\"\ r=\"12\"/></svg>);
```

Here is my SVG example, but it doesn't work in IE10. Are there any opportunities to resolve this problem? Unfortunately I have no opportunity to load SVG from HTML, it should be loaded from CSS like in example:

```
http://jsfiddle.net/fgLtkn1n/1/
```

```css
.foo {
    display:inline-block;
    width:32px;
    height:32px;
    border: 1px solid gray;
    background-image: url(data:image/svg+xml,<svg\ version=\"1.1\"\ xmlns=\"http://www.w3.org/2000/svg\"\ width=\"32px\"\ height=\"32px\"\ viewBox=\"0\ 0\ 32\ 32\"><circle\ fill=\"red\"\ cx=\"16\"\ cy=\"16\"\ r=\"12\"/></svg>);
}
```

```html
<div class='foo'></div>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only full cross-browser dataURI header I found is `data:image/svg+xml; charset=utf8,`.

Also, you'll  probably need to `encodeURI` your svg markup :

```css
.foo {
    display:inline-block;
    width:32px;
    height:32px;
    border: 1px solid gray;
    background-image: url('data:image/svg+xml; charset=utf8, %3Csvg%20version%3D%221.1%22%20xmlns%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2Fsvg%22%20width%3D%2232px%22%20height%3D%2232px%22%20viewBox%3D%220%200%2032%2032%22%3E%3Ccircle%20fill%3D%22red%22%20cx%3D%2216%22%20cy%3D%2216%22%20r%3D%2212%22%2F%3E%3C%2Fsvg%3E');
}
```

```html
<div class='foo'></div>
```

Comment: Works perfect! Just js encodeURI function or something else?

Comment: for this example I used `encodeURIComponent()`, but `encodeURI()` should work too.

Comment: For me, the problem was my SVG used an inline `<style>` tag. IE10 chokes on that apparently, so I had to strip that and apply the styles directly on the `<path>`, `<fill>`, whatever elements. Actually, I just used [SVGO](https://github.com/svg/svgo) on the SVG and that removed it for me.